# How to queue FME output on the same workspace?

Tags: fme-form, csv

I have an .csv  coordinate file with the following header

**num       xc    yc      xmin     ymin    xmax     ymax**

I want to tranform  the x/y coordinates on each line of this file to lat / long (LL84)

I am using the following workspace

[image]

The output file is a **csv** file with the lat/long.
The problem I have is FME writing the lat/long to the output file in a different line for each pair of coordinates **xc/yc** , **xmin/ymin**, **xmax/ymax** and not in the same line as it is in the input **csv**. So the results look something like this,

[image]

Is it possible to get it to work  or I have to output three different csv files and merge them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain three AttributeReprojector transformers together, each operating on a different pair of attributes.  No need to use PointAdders or BoundsExtractors.

`CSV Reader -> AttrReprojector1 -> AttrReprojector2 -> AttrReprojector3 -> CSV Writer`

Comment: excellent. Worked great. In this case initial attribute values are replaced by the reprojected attribute values.If someone wants to keep the initial attribute values (ie the xc/yc,xmin/ymin,/xmax/ymax) coordinates in the initial reference system) as well ??

Comment: An AttributeCopier transformer before you start reprojecting should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute links are not apparent from your picture, but im guessing you have xmin and xmax from boundextractor2 and ymin and ymax from boundsextractor3. When you split your workflow into 3 branches you are effectively making 3 features from one. I think the only thing you need is 1 2dpoint adder (creates an actual spatial feature) -> reprojector -> bounds_extractor, from which you get all 4 attributes.

Comment: I have xc/yc from BoundExtractor_1, xmin/ymin from BoundExtractor_2 and xmax/ymax from BoundExtractor_3. I have 6 coordinate attributes and 1 identifier (number). Using a 2d point adder doesnt allow me to populate all 6 coordinates to the output file rather one pair of x/y.

Comment: True, but you get the other 4 from bounds extractor